# Windws Store App - Convert String into Color in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, windows-store-apps, c#-to-vb.net

There is no FromName method available in VB.NET for Windows Store Apps. How can I convert string to color? I want to set an object's fillcolor by passing string value of color.

I found this workaround for C#

```
public static Color FromName(string name)
{
     var property = typeof(Colors).GetRuntimeProperty(name);
     return (Color)property.GetValue(null);
}
```

I can't seem to translate it into equivalent VB.NET code.

I also tried to write Windows Runtime Component using the above code but it says GetRunTimeProperty is not even defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Function FromName(ColName As String) As SolidColorBrush
        Dim [property] = System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperty(GetType(Windows.UI.Colors), ColName)
        Return New SolidColorBrush(DirectCast([property].GetValue(Nothing), Windows.UI.Color))
End Function
```

And done!

Comment: Great job! Nothing more rewarding than solving your own problem.

Comment: Yes (: Object Browser came to rescue :P I searched for GetRuntimeProperty and that was where my hope come to life.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
Public Shared Function FromName(name As String) As Color
    Dim [property] = GetType(Colors).GetRuntimeProperty(name)
    Return DirectCast([property].GetValue(Nothing), Color)
End Function
```

Comment: I already tried the bot translations Carl. And no, it didn't work.

Comment: It says GetRuntimeProperty is not a member of System.Type

Comment: Very strange the MSDN documentation for [RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperty Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions.getruntimeproperty.aspx) says that it is supported in Windows 8.

Comment: I am using 8.1, it maybe the issue? I tried In VS2012 as well as VS2013 Preview.

Comment: Yeah, I do not see any newer documentation for Windows 8.1, but it could very well be that there are changes to reflection in Windows 8.1 that are not yet documented on MSDN. Sorry I cannot help, good luck to you with this.

Comment: I can't believe I did it!!! Thanks for your help Karl. Please see the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

GetRuntimeProperty is an extension method, not a member of System.Type. You need to Import System. Reflection to use it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx for more on extension methods in VB